# How to Detect Windows Operating System Type

Tags: c#

I want to get windows system type whether it is 32 bit or 64 bit?

is it applicable ??

if yes please tell me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using .NET Framework 4.0 you can use `Environment` class to get the operating system info

Try This:

```
bool is64bit = Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem;
```